# Debugging R Code in pycharm: can not run user defined function?

Tags: r, pycharm

I have a very simple R script (actually just a few lines extracted from a "real" one..)

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("klaR"))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("caret"))
# The diabetes data has been modified with a header line
wdat <- read.csv('/git/uni/data/pima-indians-diabetes.csv', header=TRUE)

X <- wdat[,-c(9)]
Y <- wdat[,9]
set.seed(1)

xsquared = function(x) { x * x}

for (wi in 1:2) {
  ttSplitx <- createDataPartition(y=Y, p=.8, list=FALSE)
  Xx <- X
  nxTrain <- Xx[ttSplitx, ]
  nyTrain <- Y[ttSplitx]
  labelTrue <- nyTrain>0
  posCnt <- nxTrain[labelTrue, ]
  negCnt <- nxTrain[!labelTrue,]
  posMean <- sapply(posCnt, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  posSd <- sapply(posCnt, sd, na.rm=TRUE)
  posOffsets <- t(t(nxTrain)-posMean)
  posScaled <- t(t(posOffsets)/posSd)
  posLogs <- -(1/2)*rowSums(apply(posScaled,c(1, 2),
    function(x) { x * x} ), na.rm=TRUE)-sum(log(posSd))   # Line 25
    # function(x) { xsquared(x)  }), na.rm=TRUE)-sum(log(posSd)) # Line 26
}
print('done')
```

The above code runs with debugging enabled in about three seconds.

But when the `line26` is used instead of `line25` by swapping the commenting - it will *run* but under *debug* mode will hang indefinitely.

```
  posLogs <- -(1/2)*rowSums(apply(posScaled,c(1, 2),
    #function(x) { x * x} ), na.rm=TRUE)-sum(log(posSd))   # Line 25
    function(x) { xsquared(x)  }), na.rm=TRUE)-sum(log(posSd)) # Line 26
```

This indicates unambiguously that the `pycharm` is unable to debug into

```
xsquared = function(x) { x * x}
```

This is true for *any* function that I try to define.

So .. why can user functions not be invoked through the `pycharm` `R` debugger?

Comment: [Plugin issue tracker](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/r4intellij/issues) could be helpful

Comment: ya i had added an issue there - but neglected to update this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue was raised with the plugin developer- who responded that the feature is not presently available.

https://github.com/holgerbrandl/r4intellij/issues/174